# angular: how to forbid rgba() compile to #rrggbbaa

Tags: css, angular

Some browser not support #rrggbbaa but support rgba().
However in my angular project, `background-color: rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.9)` in `common.css` was compiled to `background-color:#3a3a3ae6` in style.[hash].css. How should I do to forbid this compile?
My project enviroment:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
"@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
"@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa), the only browser that doesn't support HEXA is IE for now. In angular 12, there's disabled support for IE, also for CSS.

If you really need support such a browser, there's a `.browserslistrc` file in angular project directory. For angular 12, default values should be:

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

as config says, remove `not` prefix in `not IE 11`.

Note, that will generate also more JavaScript code to polyfill unsupported functions in IE11.

#### Less elegant solution

Or you can just put that one property in `style` tag in your `index.html`. Should work too.

Comment: Thank you! At last I make it by add style by js. The  browser is wechat internal browser in android mobile.  Wechat internal browser in iphone is ok.